# Firebase Storage upload always times out ("storage/retry-limit-exceeded" error)

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm writing a script using the Firebase JavaScript (client, not admin) SDK to handle uploading a large quantity of images (~1.5 mb each) from an external download link to Google Firebase Storage, and I cannot successfully upload a single image.

Here's the piece of code that I'm testing out with a single image URL:

```
const firebaseConfig = {
    // firebase config details
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const storage = getStorage(app);
storage.maxOperationRetryTime = 120000;
storage.maxUploadRetryTime = 120000;

const addImageToFirebase = async (url) => {
  const download = await fetch(url);    
  const blob = await download.blob();

  const path = "test-folder/test-file.png";
  const imageRef = ref(storage, path);

  try {
    await uploadBytes(imageRef, blob);
    console.log('success!');
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}

const imageUrl = // download link for test url ;

addImageToFirebase(imageUrl);
```

When running the code, I get the following error in the terminal, no matter how long I set the maxOperationRetyTime or maxUploadRetryTime:

```
[StorageError [FirebaseError]: Firebase Storage: Max retry time for operation exceeded, please try again. (storage/retry-limit-exceeded)] {
  code: 'storage/retry-limit-exceeded',
  customData: { serverResponse: null },
  _baseMessage: 'Firebase Storage: Max retry time for operation exceeded, please try again. (storage/retry-limit-exceeded)'
}
```

Does anyone know why the upload would fail to go through?